# STUCK on C++ input file/output file program

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that reads temperature data from a file (`Temp2012.txt`), processes it, and writes the results to another file (`Temps2012.out`). The program calculates various statistics, including the average, maximum, and minimum temperatures, as well as the number of days with temperatures above the average.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("Temps2012.txt");

    if (!inputFile) {
        cout << "Error opening the file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int temperatures[31];
    int temp;
    int sum = 0;
    int maxTemp = 100;
    int minTemp = -100;
    int daysAboveAvg = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 31 && inputFile >> temp) {
        temperatures[i] = temp;
        sum += temp;

        if (temp > maxTemp) {
            maxTemp = temp;
        }

        if (temp < minTemp) {
            minTemp = temp;
        }

        i++;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    int average = (sum * 10) / 31;

    for (int i = 0; i < 31; ++i) {
        if (temperatures[i] > average) {
            daysAboveAvg++;
        }
    }

    ofstream outputFile("Temps2012.out");

    if (!outputFile) {
        cout << "Error creating the output file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    outputFile << "Average Temperature: " << (average / 10) << "." << (average % 10) << "°F" << endl;
    outputFile << "Maximum Temperature: " << maxTemp << "°F" << endl;
    outputFile << "Minimum Temperature: " << minTemp << "°F" << endl;
    outputFile << "Days Above Average: " << daysAboveAvg << " days" << endl;

    outputFile.close();

    cout << "Results written to Temps2012.out" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My results are:

```
Average Temperature: 80.4°F
Maximum Temperature: 90°F
Minimum Temperature: 70°F
Days Above Average: 0 days
```

My output file results keep getting:

**Days Above Average: 0 days**

It should be above that number.

Here are the numbers from my input file:

```
87
72
89
75
88
80
84
82
86
71
78
73
82
76
79
83
85
74
90
77
70
89
83
75
84
76
88
72
87
81
77
```

How do I fix the `Days Above Average 0 days` issue?

Comment: We can't debug your program for you. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating `average` incorrectly (and subsequently, displaying it incorrectly).

DO NOT multiply the `sum` by 100. Your calculated `average` is `804`, which of course none of the input values are greater than, hence why `daysAboveAvg` stays 0.

Calculate the `average` as a `float` or `double` instead of `int`, using the calculated `sum` as-is:

```
double average = double(sum) / 31;
```

Then you will get the result you are looking for:

> Days Above Average: 16 days

If you want to control how many decimal places are output by `operator<<` for a `float`/`double`, use the `std::setprecision` stream manipulator, eg:

```
#include <iomanip>

outputFile << "Average Temperature: " << fixed << setprecision(1) << average << "°F" << endl;
```

---

On a side note: you are also calculating `maxTemp` and `minTemp` incorrectly, too.

Given the code and input you have shown, no input values are less than your default min of `-100`, or greater than your default max of `100`, so your claim that the output says:

```
Maximum Temperature: 90°F
Minimum Temperature: 70°F
```

Cannot be true, as `if (temp > maxTemp)` and `if (temp < minTemp)` will simply never evaluate as `true`.

You need to initialize `maxTemp` and `minTemp` to the 1st value in your `temperatures[]` array, and then compare them with the remaining array values:

```
if (i == 0 || temp > maxTemp) {
    maxTemp = temp;
}

if (i == 0 || temp < minTemp) {
    minTemp = temp;
}
```